# How to programmatically load a rendered view exposed filter block

Tags: 8, blocks, views

I'm in Drupal 8 trying to load a Views Exposed Filter block based on its ID, similarly to how I would load a content block.

```
$bid = 'exposedformview_nameview_display_name'; // Found on mysite.test/admin/structure/block/manage/exposedformview_nameview_display_name/
$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load($bid);
$render = \Drupal::entityManager()
        ->getViewBuilder('block_content')
        ->view($block);
return $render;
```

Nothing ends up printing out, and in the error log I see this message:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\block_content\BlockContentViewBuilder::view() must implement interface Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface, null given

Sure enough, when I `debug($block)`, it shows NULL.

I know this works for other blocks created in the content placement area, not sure why it wouldn't also work for views exposed filter blocks.  They are both available for placement in the manage blocks page.

EDIT: It seems as though it will not be possible to load the block like this.  This method depends on revisions being available for blocks.  There is no revision for a views exposed filter block so there must be another way to accomplish this.  Perhaps by loading the form directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The block content entity is not the block entity that is required there.

The actual block entity is a configuration entity. Use the \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load method to load it.

Try the following:

```
$bid = 'exposedformview_nameview_display_name';
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($bid);
$render = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getViewBuilder('block')
        ->view($block);
return $render;
```

Comment: Also note that the entity manager service is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: Since the exposed form view blocks do not have revisions, I don't think it will be possible to load this in the same way a regular content block would be loaded.

Comment: The above code has no relation to revisions. You tired to load the wrong entity.

Comment: This is the error received from the above code:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Drupal\\block\\Entity\\Block::isDefaultRevision() in /var/www/html/src/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityViewBuilder.php on line 164

Comment: Fixed I kept the block_content as the entity type by accident.